# Clustered barplot using the mean

Tags: r, plot

I am new to R, and I am trying to figure out how to create a clustered bar chart the mean interest in a film, but separated by gender. 
Here is my dataframe:

```
i      gender film interest
1       male    1       22
2       male    1       13
3       male    1       16
4       male    1       10
5       male    1       18
6       male    1       24
7       male    1       13
8       male    1       14
9       male    1       19
10      male    1       23
11      male    2       37
12      male    2       20
13      male    2       16
14      male    2       28
15      male    2       27
16      male    2       18
17      male    2       32
18      male    2       24
19      male    2       21
20      male    2       35
21    female    1        3
22    female    1       15
23    female    1        5
24    female    1       16
25    female    1       13
26    female    1       20
27    female    1       11
28    female    1       19
29    female    1       15
30    female    1        7
31    female    2       30
32    female    2       25
33    female    2       31
34    female    2       36
35    female    2       23
36    female    2       14
37    female    2       21
38    female    2       31
39    female    2       22
40    female    2       14
```

Here is the script that is used:

```
movies<-read.csv(file.choose())
t.test(interest~film, data = movies)
names(movies)
str(movies)
movies$ï..gender = factor(movies$ï..gender, levels=c(1,2), 
labels=c("male","female"))
with(movies, table(film,interest))
summary(movies)
movie.types<-split(movies$interest, movies$film)
boxplot(movie.types)
movie.mean<-sapply(movie.types,mean)

barplot(movie.mean, col = "red", main = "Mean Interest by Film", 
ylim=c(0,30), names.arg = c("Bridget Jones Diary","Memento"))
```

And here is the barplot I made, which I need to make a cluster plot to divide out by gender:

[image]

Comment: Please paste your script as text in the question. An image of text is useless for anybody trying to help.

Comment: I think what you are getting at is just: `barplot(tapply(movies$interest, movies[c("film","gender")], FUN=mean), beside=TRUE)` - this will split the results by film+gender and plot the means as separate bars.

Comment: sorry, I will paste the script as text @thelatemail. Also, I get the following error: Error in `[.data.frame (movies, c("film", "i..gender")) : 
  undefined columns selected'

Comment: `Error in [.data.frame (movies, c("film", "i..gender")) : undefined columns selected`

Comment: Your column is named `ï..gender` not `i..gender` - notice the umlaut on the `ï` vs `i`.

Comment: You're so great, thank you!!!!